# Profile hover effect not working

Tags: discussion

I had recently asked [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35198/making-parts-of-image-transparent-am-i-doing-it-right), and noticed that the effect of increased profile area, showing details of a person, which activates when we hover on one's profile picture, was not working for me.

To explain what I exactly mean, try hovering your mouse over the profile picture of Random O'Reilly which is just beside mine in that question. Notice the profile expands and shows details. But this does not work for me.

This is especially of concern as my same profile works can be seen working here in [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329215/set-cursor-position-in-content-editable-div).

[Quick link to profile](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/21926/gaurang-tandon) if you need it.

I thought I should report this so the developers might have a look.

I know this is kind of site bug, but since it happens only on GD.SE, I am posting this here.

Sorry if I missed anything!

**UPDATE:**

Ok, as pointed out by [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa), turns out that as I have low reputation, the effect doesn't work. But then, what is the rep limit after which that effect is enabled?

Comment: I think its because you dont have enough reputation, it also does not work for you on the other sites with low reputation.

Comment: I see, I should have investigated more. Looks like possibly an issue from my side.

Comment: I think its a 1000 points

Comment: @joojaa Ok, thanks, I will try and get up to 1000 points quickly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this is how those user cards work on all SE sites. They expand when a user has 1,000+ rep (plus other criteria).

Here's the full info on Meta.SE:

### [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

Comment: "User Cards" - interesting name! Thanks for the info and link.